# Setup Puppet to email failed reports

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alerting on Failed Puppet Status](https://serverfault.com/questions/335819/alerting-on-failed-puppet-status)

How can I setup Puppet to email failed reports to an address?

I’ve setup `puppet.conf` like this

```
[master]
    server = puppet.site.net
[main]
    #dns_alt_names = puppet.site.net
    report = true
    #pluginsync = true
    # The Puppet log directory.
    # The default value is '$vardir/log'.
    logdir = /var/log/puppet

    # Where Puppet PID files are kept.
    # The default value is '$vardir/run'.
    rundir = /var/run/puppet

    # Where SSL certificates are kept.
    # The default value is '$confdir/ssl'.
    ssldir = $vardir/ssl

[agent]
    # The file in which puppetd stores a list of the classes
    # associated with the retrieved configuratiion.  Can be loaded in
    # the separate ``puppet`` executable using the ``--loadclasses``
    # option.
    # The default value is '$confdir/classes.txt'.
    classfile = $vardir/classes.txt

    # Where puppetd caches the local configuration.  An
    # extension indicating the cache format is added automatically.
    # The default value is '$confdir/localconfig'.
    localconfig = $vardir/localconfig
```

I’ve [seen a post](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/reporting.html). But it’s for everything.

I need only failures. Both on master & clients.
Can someone help me with a working conf & setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have more luck using [Foreman](http://theforeman.org/projects/foreman/wiki/Summarized_E-Mail_Reports) for this purpose.

If you can code in Ruby, you can add more features in Foreman to email on very specific errors or events, and to different people etc.